# Retry action not triggering alert again

Tags: swift, swiftui, alert

I've been trying to create a function that can be retried after showing an alert, but for some reason the second time the function runs, the alert is not showing up. I would like to have the throwing function be rerun on the retry action.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SplashScreen: View {
    @State private var shouldPresentAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .onAppear {
                performPotentiallyThrowingFunction()
            }
            .alert("Thrown", isPresented: $shouldPresentAlert) {
                Button("Retry", role: .cancel) {
                    performPotentiallyThrowingFunction()
                }
            } message: {
                Text("Something went wrong")
            }
    }

    private func performPotentiallyThrowingFunction() {
        do {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        } catch {
            shouldPresentAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert isn't getting closed yet, so setting it to `true` again doesn't have any effect.

To have it work as expected, you can close the `Alert` by setting `shouldPresentAlert` to `false` and then, on the next run loop or later, setting it to `true`

```
struct SplashScreen: View {
    @State private var shouldPresentAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .onAppear {
                performPotentiallyThrowingFunction()
            }
            .alert("Thrown", isPresented: $shouldPresentAlert) {
                Button("Retry", role: .cancel) {
                    shouldPresentAlert = false
                    Task {
                        performPotentiallyThrowingFunction()
                    }
                }
            } message: {
                Text("Something went wrong")
            }
    }

    private func performPotentiallyThrowingFunction() {
        do {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        } catch {
            shouldPresentAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```